# VBA Macro with offset

Tags: excel, macros, offset, vba

I'm trying to create a simple macro for a sheet I use every day at work.

Basically it's about:

Sheet 1 Cell A2:A11 has values in it those values need to be copy pasted into sheet 2 to with an offset each day to the next free column.

What I've got so far is the copy paste with one offset...but I don't know how to say that the offset should happen for the next free column.

```vb
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Range("A2:A11").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
If rng Is Nothing Then
    'if nothing found - search for last non empty column
    Set rng = ws.Range("2:2").Find(What:="*", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    If rng Is Nothing Then
         Set rng = rng.Offset(, 1)
         ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing an End IF and rng isn't set before you test it for Is Nothing.

Comment: @Jenni post the rest of your code, this current code can't run

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, try just using this instead of all your current code

```
Range("A2:A11").Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Set rng = rng.End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1)`
You go all the way right and then one more for the next free column.